# getElementById is returning null when trying to access an SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I am trying to write a script that will dynamically create an SVG element and display it. However, when I set the ID of the SVG element and then try to access it with Document.getElementById(), it returns null. I am using window.onload to make sure that the document will have loaded before calling the script.

```
<body>
  <script>
  function buildSVG(color) {
  const shape = `<rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90" stroke="black" fill="${color}"/>`;
  return shape;
}


function addSVG(color) {
  let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svg.id = "svgID";
  let elem = document.getElementById("svgID");
  elem.setAttribute('width', '600');
  svg.setAttribute('height', '250');
  svg.innerHTML = buildSVG(color);
  svg.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid black');
  document.body.appendChild(svg);
}
  window.onload = addSVG("cyan");
  </script>
</body>
```

I would expect a cyan square to be displayed. However, I get the error "cannot read property setAttribute of null".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: ```let elem = document.getElementById("svgID");
  elem.setAttribute('width', '600');
  svg.setAttribute('height', '250');```

Do you mean to be setting width and height on two separate variables? I don't think you need to create the svg and then get the element by ID. I think you can just work directly off of the svg variable.

Comment: It has to be added to the DOM before you can query it.

Comment: I just wanted to check if setting any attribute using elem would work. Am I not allowed to access an element via 2 different variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your svg-element you already have a reference to it in the variable you assigned. No need to get it again from the document. That would even not be possible, since it is not yet added to the document. Here is the corrected code:

```js
function buildSVG(color) {
  const shape = `<rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90" stroke="black" fill="${color}"/>`;
  return shape;
}


function addSVG(color) {
  let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svg.id = "svgID";
  svg.setAttribute('width', '600');
  svg.setAttribute('height', '250');
  svg.innerHTML = buildSVG(color);
  svg.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid black');
  document.body.appendChild(svg);
}
window.onload = addSVG("cyan");

// after 1 second: get the svgID-element and change the border.
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('svgID').setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px dashed red');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is it only added to the document after the script finishes? If I added another script element and queried using the ID would it work?

Comment: Sure, then you use `document.getElementById('svgID')`. I added an example in the code that changes the border of the svg-element after 1 second.